# CMake difficulties using OpenCV compiled with CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv-stitching

I'm implementing a video stitching paper and using CMake to generate make file. It seems like CMake is somehow failed to pass correct args for compiler when it compiles a code with OpenCV's stitching module (especially blender part). The make progress stops with this error:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -DOPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED -I/home/kra/dev/Stitcher/include -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include/opencv  -Wall -Wextra -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/stitcher.dir/src/solver.cpp.o -c /home/kra/dev/Stitcher/src/solver.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:55,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp:50,
                 from /home/kra/dev/Stitcher/src/utilities.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::~_Vector_base() [with _Tp = cv::cuda::GpuMat; _Alloc = std::allocator<cv::cuda::GpuMat>]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:425:33:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = cv::cuda::GpuMat; _Alloc = std::allocator<cv::cuda::GpuMat>]’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp:126:18:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class cv::cuda::GpuMat’
         - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp:50,
                 from /home/kra/dev/Stitcher/src/utilities.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:717:22: note: forward declaration of ‘class cv::cuda::GpuMat’
     class CV_EXPORTS GpuMat;
```

- Ubuntu 16.04
- OpenCV 3.4.1

My CMake looks like below:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 3.2)
PROJECT(VideoStitcher CXX)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")

FILE(GLOB all_sources "src/*.cpp")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(stitcher ${all_sources})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
  stitcher
  boost_filesystem
  boost_system
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

It's weird because OpenCV successfully built all CPP examples and I can even  build *stitching_detailed.cpp* example with CMake similar to above. Below is my OpenCV build info:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               3.4.1
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/kra/Softwares/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3.4.1-dirty
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2018-06-06T22:48:37Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.13.0-43-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RelWithDebInfo
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (9 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt cudart nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency sfm shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    js world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv dnn_modern java matlab ovis python2 ts viz
--     Applications:                examples apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.18.9)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.48.2)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.32)
--     TIFF:                        /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/lib/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.8)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
--            at:                   /home/kra/Softwares/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
--               at:                /home/kra/Softwares/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_lnx
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.2.92)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 8.0, CUFFT CUBLAS)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/kra/Softwares/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1 (ver 3.6.2)
--     numpy:                       /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.6/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/oc/bin/python3.5
--     Pylint:                      /home/kra/Softwares/anaconda3/bin/pylint (ver: 1.7.2, checks: 116)
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried various method to add CUDA to CMake but no luck. I can't find similar problem on Internet either.

Comment: Looks more like a problem in your `.cpp` code, not in the `CMakeLists.txt`. I am not an expert in OpenCV, but including `/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp` at the very beginning may be a bad idea. Include `opencv2/core.hpp` or some other "more general" header before it.

Comment: I doubt that's the issue. First, I tried moving the blenders header file at the bottom of the cpp code but the result was the same. Second, the code and CMake is totally fine on my Macbook Pro without CUDA.